# Dynamic Authentication and Authorization Mechanism

Tags: jsf, authentication, spring-security, authorization, spring-ldap

I am developing a web application consisting of different domains. I have tried to implement hierarchical RBAC for authorization. Each domain has some predefined operations in their bo implementations. The following is my bo package hierarchy.

com.mycompany.bo
...domain1
...domain2
   .
...domainN
...rbac

I predefine the following role hierachy at first deployment, i don't want to maintain the rbac operations after the first deployment, i mean the domain rbac operations should be self maintainable by the domain admins.

```
                Root
Domain1Admin Domain2Admin .. DomainNAdmin
```

The root role can authorize on all operations under bo implementations and also each domain admin can authorize on its all own operations and some rbac operations like create user, edit user, create role etc also.
 Finally, I have developed the ui part of the project abiding by the facelet facilities, like include tag so that i can distinguish the ui fragments of a page. As a result, I can render a ui fragment with respect to whether the the user authorized to view the fragment or not. **Any suggestion for the authorization design of the system will greatly be helpful.**

Now, I came to authentication part of the project. In this system a user does not only authenticate over internally but also should authenticate over an external system via a web service or ldap, since the user may have been already created in there.

Spring framework provides some facilities authentication via ldap(statically configurable in xml). In my case, I want to add remove edit new LDAP definitions in runtime and can change a user authentication method(may be selecting the new LDAP from a combobox). **How can I dynamically add new LDAP definitions in Spring, shall I continue with spring security or implement this feature own my own?**